# Feed list to the table list collection property in Transfer SQL Server Object Task SSIS

Tags: ssis, ssis-2012

For a Transfer SQL Server Object Task I would like to store collection of tables in a variable, and assign this variable to the ObjectsToCopy.TablesList property with an expression. Is there a way to feed this list via a variable to the TableList collection property?